# Dynamically insert script and execute immediately

Tags: javascript

I'm building a webservice that automatically combines and minifies a website's javascript. The web owner would just include the following js snippet in the website head, and it creates the minified file and appends it to the head element.

The issue I'm seeing is that when a script is dynamically appended it is not necessarily executed before the rest of the body. Since many sites may expect the head scripts to execute before the body is generated, this is an issue.

Is there any way I can force the dynamically appended script to execute before anything else? Maybe there is a workaround, like removing the entire body and reinserting it after the appending script loads.. although that seems pretty hacky.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var minify_files = new Array(
        'domain.com/js/one.js',
        'domain.com/js/two.js',
        'domain.com/js/three.js'
    );
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="minifyservice.com/minify.js"></script>
```

Comment: Write what you plan to execute as a function and call it from within, once you insert script you function will execute.

Comment: Can't do that because what is executed is a minified and combined version of all the files in the "minify_files" array. The point of this service is that site owners just embed the above code and it just works.

Comment: so you NEED your script that you provide to be executed FIRST? is it reasonable to expect your users to place the script at the TOP of the page

Comment: by top of the page, i mean top of the head, or at least BEFORE OTHER SCRIPT tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="minifyservice.com/minify.js"></script>
```

Would go before the user's code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    minify_files([
        'domain.com/js/one.js',
        'domain.com/js/two.js',
        'domain.com/js/three.js'
    ]);
</script>
```

or something similar would probably work better. minify.js would define the function minify_files which would be something like this:

```
function minify_files(paths) {
    var query="";
    for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
        query += encodeURIComponent(paths[i]);
        query += i < paths.length - 1 ? "&" : "";
    }
    document.write(
        "<scri" + "pt src=\"minifyservice?" + 
        query + "\"><scri" + "pt>"
    );
}
```

untested. But should be a good starting place. Because of document.write, it will block and ensure the scripts load before the page loads, but will only work before the page finishes rendering. (keep it in the head or at least before you close the body tag.)

Answer (score 0):

- i think you will need to ask/require
  that users place the script tag
  before any other assets.
- place your script array in
  querystring.
- backend service combines and returns script

`<script type="text/javascript" src="site.com/mini.js?script1&script2"></script>`